# regex replace in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to replace the list guid in this string from:

`<Field Type=\"Lookup\" DisplayName=\"Human Resources Document Category\" Required=\"FALSE\" EnforceUniqueValues=\"FALSE\" List=\"{28365191-64ab-4b28-9ebe-427d66ed4e3a}\" WebId=\"a033826b-2bc7-4f95-8054-2fd4423c53d0\" ShowField=\"Title\" Mult=\"FALSE\" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary=\"FALSE\" Group=\"Custom Columns\" ID=\"{b87d7bc5-43da-490d-8303-ecbb0702bcd3}\" SourceID=\"{a033826b-2bc7-4f95-8054-2fd4423c53d0}\" StaticName=\"Human_x0020_Resources_x0020_Document_x0020_Category\" Name=\"Human_x0020_Resources_x0020_Document_x0020_Category\" Version=\"1\" />`

So I want to change List="{guid}" to `"{b87d7bc5-43da-490d-8303-ecbb0702bcd3}"`

Can't seem to find the regex for doing this. Trying a `String.Replace` but can't seem to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, updated with new guid.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
var input1 = "<Field Type=\"Lookup\" DisplayName=\"Human Resources Document Category\" Required=\"FALSE\" EnforceUniqueValues=\"FALSE\" List=\"{28365191-64ab-4b28-9ebe-427d66ed4e3a}\" WebId=\"a033826b-2bc7-4f95-8054-2fd4423c53d0\" ShowField=\"Title\" Mult=\"FALSE\" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary=\"FALSE\" Group=\"Custom Columns\" ID=\"{b87d7bc5-43da-490d-8303-ecbb0702bcd3}\" SourceID=\"{a033826b-2bc7-4f95-8054-2fd4423c53d0}\" StaticName=\"Human_x0020_Resources_x0020_Document_x0020_Category\" Name=\"Human_x0020_Resources_x0020_Document_x0020_Category\" Version=\"1\" />";
var pattern1 = "(?<=List=\\\").*?(?=\\\")";
var replace = "{b87d7bc5-43da-490d-8303-ecbb0702bcd3}";
var res = Regex.Replace(input1, pattern1, replace);
```